# Strange behavior in Internet Explorer when binding to array with Ember.js

Tags: internet-explorer, ember.js

I have come across some strange behavior in IE8 (surprise) when binding to an array with Ember.js.

Every time an array is updated IE8 inserts blank space around the bound values. Does anyone know if it is a known issue or if there are any work around.

Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/JZbCv/16/

Comment: Am I missing something, or your jsfiddle is empty ?

Comment: Sorry it was. I've updated the link.

Comment: When putting jsfiddle, please avoid to link static resources, as it does'nt wor for all who try to help you ;). It does not matter for jquery, Ember.js etc, but your bindingTestApp.js script, I don't know what is it. see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/JZbCv/6/

Comment: The code for the bindingTestApp.js is in the JavaScript pane.

Comment: Ok, fine, so I've updated some things, because even in Chrome, nothing was displayed. Did you see weird behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/JZbCv/14/ ?

Comment: I've updated and tested this time.